# etherbase address changes automatically in a private network

Tags: private-blockchain, coinbase, pow

I am running a private Ethereum PoW network, which has a miner with a public IP address. Unfortunately, my miner's etherbase address is switching to an unknown address: "0x59fab640fe53497a5a3f5db83e027ee108a354ab"
Even if I set it to an other address, it switches back to this address.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to prevent it?